# Py.Test test reusability best practices

Tags: python, pytest

Suppose I'm testing the process of user interaction on a RESTful server. Many of my tests require that I have a valid user on my database, and of course I want to test the user creation. So, in py.test I would write something like this:

```
def test_user_creation():
    '''user creation goes here'''

def test_user_update_values():
    '''should create an user and validate the new values'''
```

The question is, what's the best practice to reuse the creation process? A fixture? call the first test case and return the user to the second one? Or to replicate everything for each test? The later alternative albeit more isolated can be a PITA if you need to refactor parts of the code forcing you to modify all tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all comes down to preferences, in this case I would say fixtures are your best bet. Although you might be able to use parametrized tests as well:

Example from: https://pytest.org/latest/example/parametrize.html

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

testdata = [(datetime(2001, 12, 12), datetime(2001, 12, 11), timedelta(1)),
            (datetime(2001, 12, 11), datetime(2001, 12, 12), timedelta(-1)),
            ]


@pytest.mark.parametrize("a,b,expected", testdata)
def test_timedistance_v0(a, b, expected):
    diff = a - b
    assert diff == expected
```